# How to change Apple Developer account

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have received an invite to my company's developer team, but I have accepted it with my personal email, instead of job email address. And I think that is the reason why I can't get iTunes Connect work now, since I got and accepted an invite for it at my job email. Now when I try to log in to iTunes Connect I get a message:

> Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect. Learn More

Is there a way of changing the account address for the developers team?
In my account details when I log in to Apple developer my job email is set up to my account!

So, I have no idea, of how to change this initial mistake of accepting the invite with the wrong address?

Comment: It depends on the actual invite. Developer portal and iTunes Connect are actually 2 different logins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iTunesConnect uses a different account than the developer portal. I don't think it has anything to do with the different email addresses. You need to ask the admin to add the email you signed up with as a user on iTunesConnect.